# Horizontal one-armed bandit animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create something like a horizontal one-armed bandit game.

I have 12 elements placed next to each other, and when I press a button I want them to move horizontally and stop at a random position.

Can you give me any advice on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not very efficient but you can do something like that:

```
var move = setInterval(animation, 50); //50 is only an example value

function animation(){
  $('yourDOMelement').css('transform', 'translateY(1px)'); //maybe -1 depends on direction...
  if(Math.random()*100==2){   //adjust the 100 to your needs
    clearInterval(move);
  }
}
```

Note that the code is untested, I hope you will at least get the idea how I would do it and then adopt it for your problem.